# HD screen recording of iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-capture, xcode-simulator

I'm struggling to record a high quality video of my iOS app. There are several similar questions out there, but my focus is on *high quality*. To my knowledge there are only two options to record a screen and both have some serious limitations.

**Screen recording in the simulator**

- The quality is just not as good as on the device because of two reasons. First, OS X (Quicktime) has a built in screen recording function but the compression is very high and non-adjustable. I found screenium to give me much better result. However, even with the issue of compression solved, the color depth in the simulator is not as rich as on the device creating very visible artefact (even before recording it).
- The performance of the iOS app in the simulator is much worse than on an actual (modern) device. Especially when using OpenGL, I notice a substantial drop in the framerate.

**Recording the app on the device**

- I could just hold a camera and record the iPhone with the app running on it. For obvious reasons this doesn't seem like the ideal solution.
- I could use a third party app to record the AirPlay mirrored screen on a Mac. Again, this would involve some serious performance decrease and compression artefacts because of the encoding process.
- I could use a VGA adapter and record that, but the quality of the VGA signal is also not the same as on the device (RETINA display).

I'm looking for any kind of advice on this topic. A way to increase the color depth in the simulator, a way to increase the speed of an app in the simulator, a professional way to record the screen from the device, an efficient way to encode frames on the fly in the app...

Answer (score 2):

The iPad 2 and 3, and iPhone 4S and 5 can do screen mirroring over HDMI, using Apple's [Digital AV Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A/apple-digital-av-adapter). Combined with an HDMI capture device, this should give you the best possible quality.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the app [Reflection](http://www.reflectorapp.com).

It allows you to transmit your ios device's screen over wifi to your mac and record it at the same time. Brilliant app.